# Re-using MacBook Pro screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have an old MacBook Pro A1706 13" that I would like to turn its screen into an external monitor.
I can't find the reference of the screen that I'm supposed to check to buy the correct LCD controller board.
And I don't want to dissemble it from the aluminum cover (I've separated it from the keyboard/body part of the MacBook Pro, but I would like to keep it like the original "look" with the silver back case)
Can someone know how to find that reference, please?

Comment: Apple uses different vendors (LG, Samsung, etc.) for LCD panels.  Unfortunately, you have to open it up to get the *exact* model of your LCD to get the correct driver.